# Does having more leagues enabled create more regens?

Tags: football-manager-2013

I'm confused because I've bought players from leagues that aren't enabled plenty of times, but it seems intuitively like more active teams = more players = more regens. Am I wrong?

Comment: Are you regenerating or asking about regions?

Comment: "Regens" means "computer generated players".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding more nations as playable or view-only will increase the player count and also the number of regens generated. Adding additional leagues within these nations will usually increase the player count, so your intuition is correct.

[This](http://community.sigames.com/showthread.php/315066-How-Are-Regens-Produced?s=b3f9933884e9a8558b2a8cd14a0706ac&p=8088898&viewfull=1#post8088898) post may be helpful if looking for more information on the subject.